# Verify string in PHP from URL

Tags: php, get, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site and a front end posting form on it.

When form is submitted, the user gets link to his email with unique string (example 432879374982) saved as a custom field and post gets status "pending":

http://www.mysite.com/verify.php?verify=432879374982

I now want to change status to "published" when user click on a link.

I know that I should use GET parameter, and check if the string is saved in database, and publish the post where there is a match in db, but dont know how to code this.

EDIT:

Made it working!

In the landing page- on wordpress I created a page named "verify" and in template (php) I included code from @Bora- only the database connection has to be established before and it changes the status of a post.

Status has to be set as "publish", not "published"

Comment: Then read up on it. [$_GET](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/postget.php), [PDO prepared](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PDO-Prepared-Statement-P550.html). There are thousands more if you do a google search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like following codes:

```
$verify = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['verify']); // escape GET var

$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE code = '$verify'"; // Build query

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) { // Check return query

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { // Fetch Row
        $query = "UPDATE table SET status = 'published' WHERE code = '$verify'"; // Update query
        $mysqli->query($query); // Run query
    }

    $result->close(); // free result set
}
```

Comment: The problem with this code is that the custom fields in WP (so my unique number) are not saved in the same table. I know I should get after validation of unique number the post_id and match it with id in other table, but....